# akka-http + angular2 routing

Tags: angular, akka-http

I'm trying to serve angular2(rc3) app from akka-http(scala rest framework). It doesn't work because of routing. When requested, spray tries to find `/my/endpoint/declared/in/angular` as normal resource. How should I do it?

With simple static webpages, without routing(dynamic links) it is pretty easy:

```
path("app") {
  getFromResource("my-app/index.html")
} ~ getFromResourceDirectory("my-app")
```

I've tried to serve index.html every time when requested resource is not found:

```
path("app") {
  getFromResource("my-app/index.html")
} ~ getFromResourceDirectory("my-app") ~ getFromResource("my-app/index.html")
```

but it breaks relative links( when I ask for `/app/my/endpoint` I get index.html which tries to download styles.css from `/app/my/endpoint/styles.css` instead of `/app/styles.css`)

I would like to know how it is done in other http servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. It may not be optimal but works pretty well.

In the spray config you put:

```
path("ui") { //the same prefix must be set as base href in index.html
  getFromResource("abtest-ui/index.html")
} ~ pathPrefix("ui") {
getFromResourceDirectory("abtest-ui") ~
  getFromResource("abtest-ui/index.html")
}
```

And in the index.html:

```
<base href="/ui/">
```

To summarize:

- request to `/ui/` serves index.html
- request to `/ui/someResourceFile.css` serves this resource
- request to `/ui/AnythingThat/IsNotA/ResourceFile` serves index.html and angular routing handles it